# Is it possible to visualize a cloudify blueprint?

Tags: cloudify

I'm curious if there's a tool that will visualize a cloudify blueprint?  Ideally, I'd like to trace back nodes through the imports that define the base types, to create a DAG.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tool called "Composer" which allows you to generate and visualize blueprints. Additionally, Cloudify Manager's UI shows the structure of a blueprint.

http://getcloudify.org/2017/01/31/introducing-cloudify-composer-2_3-what-expect-next.html

These are premium features though.